# Total js: F.model is returning null

Tags: javascript, total.js

Below `const deposit` is returning null value. But the same line is working in the different controller in same directory. 
I just included this lines in new controller file in same directory. Is anything else needed?

```
 const deposit = F.model('managedeposit');
```

Also other models are working there in same file like

```
const purchaseListModel = F.model('purchaselist');
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a syntax error in `managedeposit` model. Which I was trying to import. After fixing that error, everything seems working fine. :)